# How to place the last <li> on the right side of my page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to move the last `li` to right side but my CSS is not working.

```css
.gCountryFlag {
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
ul li {
    list-style: none;

}
.navbar-collapse ul li:last-child {
     float: right;
}
.gCountryFlag li {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a runat="server" href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a runat="server" href="/About.aspx">About</a></li>
                <li><a runat="server" href="/Contact.aspx">Contact</a></li>
                <li>
                    <div class="flagChangeCountry">
                        <asp:Image CssClass="topFlag" runat="server" ID="currentCultureFlagImage" />
                        <%--<asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:LocalisedText, ChangeCountryText %>" />--%>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i want to move this image to right side which is in div. here it is.

```
<li>
    <div class="flagChangeCountry">
        <asp:Image CssClass="topFlag" runat="server" ID="currentCultureFlagImage" />
        <%--<asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:LocalisedText, ChangeCountryText %>" />--%>
    </div>
</li>
```

Also, I want to align the flag image with other text in same line. Here is screenshot for how the flag is looking which is not right side and also which is not aligned with other text.

[image]

Comment: Try .nav.navbar-nav { width: 100%; }. Can you provide a working demo at codepen or jsfiddle?

Comment: did not worked .nav.navbar-nav { width: 100%; }.

Comment: There is more going on in your DOM structure than I can see here, like multiple columns or additional styles over-qualifying what you are trying to declare here. Those rules should work, and they do if you take all the provided code and run them through a code snippet. Consider updating the question to include a minimal, complete, and verifiable example that accurately demonstrates the issue for user-friendly reproduction and troubleshooting.

Comment: here is my full html. check the link https://jsfiddle.net/g2upojoc/  just notice flag image is not coming at top position. i want to align the flag image with menu text called Home | About | Contact and also i want to move the flag to right side. please check my link and modify or add css accordingly. thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to set a width to the ul, like this:

```
  ul{
    float:left;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

and here's a working example in jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/d7dtm4we/

Edit: I copied the jsfiddle, to the code snippet, and added the width 100% vs no set width

```css
.gCountryFlag {
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}

ul.nav{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float:left;
  width: 100%;
}

ul.nav2{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float:left;
}

ul li {
    list-style: none;
    float:left;
    padding: 5px
}

ul li:last-child {
     float: right;
}

.gCountryFlag li {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a runat="server" href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a runat="server" href="/About.aspx">About</a></li>
                <li><a runat="server" href="/Contact.aspx">Contact</a></li>
                <li>
                    <div class="flagChangeCountry">
                      <img src="http://satyr.io/32x20?flag=gbr" />
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav2 navbar-nav">
                <li><a runat="server" href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a runat="server" href="/About.aspx">About</a></li>
                <li><a runat="server" href="/Contact.aspx">Contact</a></li>
                <li>
                    <div class="flagChangeCountry">
                      <img src="http://satyr.io/32x20?flag=gbr" />
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: i just checked your html and css from jsfiddle and it seems it will work when i add your css in my code. thanks

Comment: Why do you set  `float:left;` for the `ul` element? Please place code from jsfiddle to code snippet.

Comment: The rest of the jsfiddle, is the same he posted in the original post, that's why I didn't add it.
 You need the 100% (or whatever width you want), since the ul will only grow until all it's child fit in.

Comment: here is my full html. check the link https://jsfiddle.net/g2upojoc/  just notice flag image is not coming at top position. i want to align the flag image with menu text called Home | About | Contact and also i want to move the flag to right side. please check my link and modify or add css accordingly. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would use `display: flex` instead of float. You have more control over your elements in display flex. In display flex you can easily adjust your element inside the box. Use flex grow to make an element bigger or smaller.

Please take a look at this [guide-to-flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: here is my full html. check the link https://jsfiddle.net/g2upojoc/  just notice flag image is not coming at top position. i want to align the flag image with menu text called Home | About | Contact and also i want to move the flag to right side. please check my link and modify or add css accordingly. thanks

Comment: @Thomas sorry for my late response. Please check the updated code. I guess this is what you are looking for. https://jsfiddle.net/g2upojoc/11/

Comment: thanks for reply. still flag is not on the right side of the page.

Comment: @Thomas but I thought you want it on top right side of the page!

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to set `float: right` for the last `li` item. And don't forget about clearfix.

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 50px;
}

ul:after { 
  /* clearfix */
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

li {
  float: left; /* all li items */
  
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid green;
  list-style: none;
}

li:last-child {
  float: right; /* last li item */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i will check and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Try add this in class `.navbar-nav`

```
.navbar-nav {
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar-collapse ul li:last-child {      
    float: right;
}
```

This is because bootstrap.css has overwritten your css file.

Comment: here is my full html. check the link https://jsfiddle.net/g2upojoc/1/  just notice flag image is not coming at top position. i want to align the flag image with menu text called Home | About | Contact and also i want to move the flag to right side. please check my link and modify or add css accordingly. thanks

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `clear:left;` before setting it `float: right;`

```
.navbar-collapse ul li:last-child {
         clear:left;
         float: right;
    }
```

Comment: Try to put it after the class ..gCountryFlag li  in css  :D

Comment: sorry not clear. give me a sample of what you are saying.

Comment: .goCountryFlag li {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
}

.navbar-collapse ul li:last-child {
     clear:left;
     float: right;
}

Comment: sorry no luck with `.goCountryFlag li { float: left; display: inline-block; margin: 5px; } .navbar-collapse ul li:last-child { float: right; }`